# Upgrading the react router version, I got 2 in my project

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am upgrading the react router version for one of my friend project

The thing is there are 2 react-router-dom. Do I need to remove both of them or just remove 1 of them is fine?

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
   
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "yup": "0.32.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: remove both of them as they are outdated for the version > 6, i think the newer version has its own types included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have two of the same NPM package installed, `@types/react-router-dom` is a different package than `react-router-dom`. The latter is the actual `react-router-dom` dependency while the former is the typescript definitions for it as a dev dependency. That said, you should try to be on the same version of both as `@types/react-router-dom` generally matches the version of the package it's typing.

From the terminal run `npm i -S react-router-dom@5.3.3` to install the same version you have the types for.

### Upgrade to RRDv6

`react-router-dom@6` is completely written in Typescript, so if you decide to upgrade to RRDv6 you no longer need the additional types package, installing `react-router-dom@6` alone is sufficient.

Remove any `@types/react-router-dom` packages that are installed.

Comment: Hi.I will be upgrading to the v6 for the `react-router-dom` but the package `@types/react-router-dom` doesn't comes out for the v6 yet. Should I remove it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router-dom

Comment: @Khant Sure, if updating to RRDv6 you no longer need the extraneous types package for it, RRDv6 is completely written in TS.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make `rm -rf node_modules` to clean it up. Remove the old router version in your json and make `nmp i`. If needed because there is no router after the deletion of the old make `npm i react-router`